# Using list of list to replace list of tuples

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I am working with earlier version of .NET and I would like a tuple replacement.  Instead of making my own tuple class I would like to use a list of list.  Would there be any issues that can come up i.e. list has not set length?

replace

```
List<(String, String, String)> myList;
```

with

```
List<List<string>> myList;
```

Also I'm making 2 of these list of tuple or list of list and comparing differences where I find all elements that exist in 1 list and not other and vice versa, so that comparison needs to be intuitive and not bloated to implement.

Comment: What version of .NET are you working with? The [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=net-5.0) _class_ has been a thing since .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 3):

You are effectively creating a jagged array. To directly answer your question: **there is nothing inherently wrong with jagged arrays, and you can definitely get this to work.** But for your use case this seems like a bit of a code smell. I would look into an approach that communicates intent.

In your first example,

```
List<(String, String, String)> myList;
```

There is some intent being communicated. The intent is that every item in the list will have three string members. That's a good start. When you switch to:

```
List<List<string>>
```

That intent is lost to anyone reading the code, which is bad for readability and maintainability.

Let's say you want to add a fourth member to each item of the list. If your list is a tuple, every piece of code that adds to the list must be updated before your code can compile. That's good because it prevents runtime errors. On the other hand, if your list is a jagged array, you can't be sure at compile time that every item in the list will contain the correct number of strings. By turning your list of tuples into a jagged array you have made your code more difficult to extend.

I would personally opt for something similar to the tuple approach, but I would write a class that defines the members by name. This goes back to communicating intent. For example:

```
record Person {}
{
    string FirstName {get; set;}
    string MiddleName {get; set;}
    string LastName {get; set;}
}

List<Person> myList;
```

In this case you won't find yourself asking "What was item1 of the tuple again?". Instead you will easily be able to interpret each item in the list.

Comment: is comparing 2 custom objects for equality a hassle? because I need to make 2 list of these objects and compare difference to see which object exist in 1 list but not other with tuple it was easy to do.

Comment: @bakalolo it used to be a hassle until C# 9. Notice that I made 'Person' a 'record' type. C# 9 allows for easy comparisons between record types. More on that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

Comment: Ok I changed my mind sticking with tuples